# Is the TOPIK 1-6 equivalent for CEFR A1 to C2?

Tags: topik

According to [the Wikipedia article on TOPIK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_of_Proficiency_in_Korean#Grading), the TOPIK level 1 to 6 is equivalent for CEFR A1 to C2, respectively. However, I'm quite doubtful of its comparison, especially because many Japanese passed TOPIK 6 but never even close to the C2 standard, I think.

[HSK score comparison on Mandarin Chinese is often criticized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanyu_Shuiping_Kaoshi#Current_structure_(since_2010)) and it is considered that the HSK 6 (highest level) is equivalent for B2 (which I agree).

JLPT is also considered not to the level [as on the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages) [by some](https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/81zjo4/how_would_you_compare_the_japanese_n15_levels/), and the N1 is on the B2 level in my opinion.

But the TOPIK score seems to be on par with CEFR from 1-6 to A1-C2, and I have never seen any argument on it. But I still think, the C2 is too high for TOPIK 6 holders. Also, given the number of participants of TOPIK 6 and the standard of CEFR C2, it is strange that TOPIK adapts even to such a high level of language learners.

So my question is, is the level 1 to 6 of TOPIK considered on par with CEFR A1 to C2, or is there any argument in Korea that opposes to it, which I might not get to in English?

Comment: I just tried the TOPIK 1 reading test, and it seems to be quite a bit above A1 level, maybe A2? So they are not exactly aligned

Answer (score 1):

Well, it does *not* seem that the TOPIK level criteria were set based on the CEFR levels. You can find several differences reading Yunhee Won's publication (the reference 8 of the Wikipedia article). I guess that is the only relevant publication pointing out both the similarity and difference between those levels.
Won mentions the following:

> In order to understand the language proficiency, speaking, listening, reading and writing in all parts should be evaluated; however, there is *no speaking test in TOPIK*, and it is unfortunate that there is *no writing test in the beginner-level test.*

Without the speaking test, I don't think the TOPIK levels correspond closely to the CEFR levels. Although [they are going to evaluate speaking skills from 2023 onwards](https://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?mode=LSD&mid=sec&sid1=102&oid=001&aid=0010589355), it still won't make the two criteria the same.